# Scala map doesn't store data

Tags: scala, dictionary

I try to save csv data to hash map. It seems to read csv file and saved well in RDD but NOT map.
I tried hashmap, map with put or += method but nothing works. Any idea of this?

```
val logFile3 = "d:/data/data.csv"

val rawdf3 = sqlContext.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
  .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
  .load(logFile3)

var activityName = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, String]()

//save key-value to RDD to check
val activityNameRDD = rawdf3.map { row =>
  activityName += (row.getAs( "key").toString -> row.getAs( "value").toString) // I think It's work but not
  println(row.getAs( "key").toString + " - " + row.getAs( "value").toString) // print all data well
  (row.getAs( "key").toString, row.getAs( "value").toString)
}
activityNameRDD.saveAsTextFile( "d:/outdata/activityName") // all csv data saved well

activityName.foreach( {row => println( row._1 + " = " + row._2)}) // print nothing

println( activityName.getOrElse( "KEY1", "NON")) // print "NON"
println( activityName.getOrElse( "KEY2", "NON")) // print "NON"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Spark?  Variables with "Rdd" suffix implies that.

If yes, then read thoroughly ["Shared Variables"](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables) section of Spark's documentation:

> Normally, when a function passed to a Spark operation (such as map or reduce) is executed on a remote cluster node, it works on separate copies of all the variables used in the function. These variables are copied to each machine, and no updates to the variables on the remote machine are propagated back to the driver program. Supporting general, read-write shared variables across tasks would be inefficient.

When you try to modify shared variable from `map` each worker modifies it's own version and updates are lost in the end. If you really need shared mutable state, consider using `Accumulator` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `var`, `mutable.Map` and mutating things as side-effects (three big no-nos in Scala), why not just do things directly? It's clearer what's going on and should also fix your issue:

```
val activityName:Map[String, String] = rawdf3.map { row =>
  row.getAs( "key").toString -> row.getAs( "value").toString
}.toMap
```